# Trouble with boost dates in Rcpp functions using BH package on RStudio 0.99

Tags: r, boost, rstudio, rcpp

I'm having some trouble with Rcpp functions which use boost objects when running them on RStudio 0.99. This issue does not occur in previous releases of RStudio (0.98) neither in the R console.

This is a sample of the cpp file that I'm using. There are two simple functions, f1 not using any boost date, and f2 with some elemental operation involving dates:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost::local_time;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int f1(int x, int y)
{
return x+y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int f2(const int hour, const int day, const int month, const int year) {

ptime pt(date(year,month,day), hours(hour));
time_zone_ptr zone(new posix_time_zone("UTC"));
local_date_time fecha(pt, zone);

double HoraUTC = fecha.utc_time().time_of_day().total_seconds() / 3600.0;

return HoraUTC;
}
```

Compilation through Rcpp::sourceCpp works ok, returning this warning about one of BH header files:

```
C:/R/RCurrent/library/BH/include/boost/datetime/posixtime/posixtimeconfig.hpp:73:79: warning: 'result' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Function f1 runs normally, but when calling f2, a typical R session crash occurs. As I have told before, this never happens in the R console nor using previous versions of RStudio.

Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LCCOLLATE=SpanishSpain.1252 LCCTYPE=SpanishSpain.1252 LCMONETARY=SpanishSpain.1252
[4] LCNUMERIC=C LCTIME=Spanish_Spain.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools3.2.0 BH1.58.0-1
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing two simple errors (you were lacking an underscore each in `posix_time` and `local_time`) your code works fine here -- all current version of R, Rcpp and BH on Ubuntu 15.04:

```
R> sourceCpp("soquestion.cpp")

R> f1(2,3)
[1] 5

R> f2(12, 12, 12, 2015)
[1] 12
R>
```

Maybe something happened which made your (binary ?) package installations to get out of whack.  You can always install from source ...

Comment: The underscores thing may have been caused by the code parser. It was ok in my trial file. In any case, the bug is only related to RStudio 0.99 (even on earlier versions is working fine...), maybe the title was not so specific. Also tried compiling BH from source with no result.  Thanks anyway for your prompt reply.

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that RStudio has anything to do with it.

Comment: Also, if the answer was helpful, please consider follow StackOverflow convention and either/or 'upvote the answer' (click on up-arrow) and/or 'accept the answer' (which only you can do) by clicking on the tickmark.

Comment: Finally I skipped the problem by including all the Rcpp functions in a package, as it's reccomended in the documentation. It works perfectly and it's quite straightforward. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you un-accepted the answer, but at least it got me back here.   I by now have a new package [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/index.html) also building on top of Boost Date_time _and we ran into the same issue_:   Crashed under RStudio.  I am friendly with that team, and it is likely an issue due to RStudio using another (older) Boost library for itself.  So this appears to be a hard block.  For anytime,  I now skip known 'crashing' functions.  Others work. YMMV.

Comment: That said, I just ran it again (via `sourceCpp()`) and functions `f1` and `f2` still work under RStudio (version 1.0.116 on Ubuntu).

Comment: Tried again and works OK with RStudio 0.99.903 on windows. The problem, probably what you point out about boost versions, seems solved in newer version of RStudio.   Your comment about `anytime`'s issues is quite useful too. Thanks.